# Proof finite stopping time and Wiener process bounded

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Let $T_{-a,b}=\inf\{t\geq 0: W_{t} \notin [-a,b]\}, a,b>0$.

I want to show that this is a finite stopping time ($P(T_{-a,b}<\infty)=1$) and that $|W_{\min(T_{-a,b},t)}|$ is bounded by a constant. Can anyone help me with this? I really don't see it. Thanks!

Comment: If you assume that $W_0=0$, then $-a\leq W_{\min(T_{-a,b},t)}\leq b$ for all $t$.

Comment: Why is that the case?

Comment: @RoosJansen By the very definition of the stopping time and the continuity of the sample paths.

Comment: Thanks! And the finity of the stopping time?